# check AmazonS3 for empty object

Tags: java, spring, aws-sdk

```
@Component
public class AwsS3Client {
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3() {
        return this.amazonS3;
    }
}
```

......

```
  @Autowired
  private AwsS3Client awsS3Client;

  if (Objects.isNull(awsS3Client.getAmazonS3())) {
      awsS3Client.createSessionWithAssumeRoleCredentials();
  }
```

But for this code `awsS3Client.getAmazonS3()` I get:

```
Required type: Object
Provided: AmazonS3
```

AmazonS3 is located into another utility jar file.
Do you know how I can fix this? I use aws sdk Version 1.11.971

Comment: Hi @Peter Penzov, can you please let us know if you are using spring , spring boot.
Also, when you say you are getting error `awsS3Client.getAmazonS3() `, does that mean you have already created new `AmazonS3` instance here? if so, can you please let me know how you have created it? thanks

Comment: I use Spring Boot. I have created new instance into separate jar file used as library.

Comment: thanks, is it not possible for you to use aws-sdk dependency as maven dependency if you use springboot?

Comment: Actually I tried this: I use aws-sdk dependency in both parent and client jar packages - and the problem is gone. But now I have a duplicated dependency. Any idea for a solution?

Comment: when you say you have parent & client jar package, does parent is also parent of client? or its separate repositories?

Comment: they are jar A and Jar B -> jar A is imported into JarB and uses java classes.

Comment: ok, can you please let me know if both jars really required aws-sdk dependency? can only one won't work for you? Sorry asking few question before posting my answer.

Comment: if I add  aws-sdk dependency as dependency into jar A and I try to import jar A into jar B and compile it I get the above error. If I add  aws-sdk dependency and jar A and import into jar B jar A and  aws-sdk dependency the error is solved. But I have duplicate import.

Comment: Does that mean, your jar B already has asw-sdk dependency ?

Comment: no, I imported it as a workaround to solve the problem from the issue above.

Comment: ok, if you remove aws-sdk dependency from jar B, are you getting same error? Because I think you should remove aws-sdk dependency from jar B & only use it for jar A

Comment: please let me know if that is case , i will put some thoughts on that

Comment: yes I also think that jar A should have aws-sdk dependency. But I get the error.

Comment: ok, you got error when you removed it from jar B? i.e. from a jar which imported another jar

Comment: yes, correct. Any idea why?

Comment: Where is above mentioned code implemented? jar B (i.e. the one which imported jar A)?
I am feeling you do have some dependencies of aws-sdk in jar A.    If you are using maven structure, do one thing, can you execute  `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`   on Jar A & see if you find `aws-sdk` dependency?

Comment: By executing `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` you can able to see what sort of dependencies you got into project

Comment: There might be case that you might have transitive dependency of `aws-sdk`

Comment: I will try to answer tomorrow if possible, in meantime, you can share if there is any further observation you got about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here.
Here is a sample of how to create an [S3Client](https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-java#creating-client-connection)

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
  "<AWS accesskey>", 
  "<AWS secretkey>"
);


AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
  .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
  .build();
```

Assuming you need a createSessionWithAssumeRoleCredentials on *AwsS3Client*,
Wouldn't it make more sense to have an S3ClientFactory which has a static method *createSessionWithAssumeRoleCredentials* which creates an S3 client for the set of credential that you pass? Credentials are required to instantiate an S3 client, so have a createSessionWithAssumeRoleCredentials method on an S3Client instance makes little sense.

If you are sure that you just need to use the S3 client with just one set of credential, then shouldn't you do something like this?

```
@Component
public class AwsS3Client {
    private S3Client amazonS3;

    public AwsS3Client(CustomAWSParameters customAWSParameters){
        return createAwsS3ClientWithCredentials(customAWSParameters.getAccessKey, customAWSParameters.getSecretKey, customAWSParameters.getAwsProperties)
    }

    private static AmazonS3 createAwsS3ClientWithCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey, AwsProperties awsProperties){
        AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);
        awsCredentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials);
        amazonS3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.of(awsS3Properties.getRegion()))
                .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
}
```

You can have type safety checks, and other exception handling after/during creating the S3Client instance.